# What is the best way to use many different instances of objects insider another PHP class?

Tags: php, html, oop

I have a class called Page, which loads a PHP file for the current page, containing all the HTML (template file). In my template file, I want to use instances of other objects, that is initialized outside the Page class (ex. User, PDO or other classes). My problem is, how I do this the smartest way.

In my page class i have a method called get_page() which loads my template file (containing all the code for my GUI.

```
public function get_page() {
        // Load theme template
        ...

        $template_file = ABSPATH_THEME . 'tpl.' . $result['template_file'] . '.php';

        if(file_exists($template_file)) {
            $page = require_once($template_file);
            return $page;   
        }
    }
```

As you see the template file are loaded inside my Page class, and therefore will it not access instances of classes initialized outside my Page class.

I can come up with different solutions:

1) I pass all instances of the different classes to my class Page, when constructing my page. I think this is the right way, but can be very complex if I need 5, 10 or 20 different objects in my design.

2) Find a way to include the template file outside the Page class, but triggered from the get_page() function - have no clue how to do this, and if it is a good solution?

Can you please tell me what is best, and if there are some better ways to do it?

Comment: sounds look a good option would be to use a template engine like Smarty

Comment: I have considered to use SMARTY but I decided not to because I wanted complete control over my theme support. And this way I am using is working well for me. But it would be nice, if I could write my template as if it was not loaded inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can just include classes on the top of your php

eg. /CLASSPATH/ClassName.php

And then you can create an entity for that class once and use it everywhere

eg. $entity = new ClassName();

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet will be to pass them in as arguments, depending on what you need you may want to make them properties.

Edit: This is assuming that by "using instances of other objects" you mean that you need to use objects that have already been instantiated elsewhere.

Comment: Was what I meant. I check user data and so before I make an instance of Page. But need user data inside my theme. To pass them in as arguments is also what I do now. But would be nice if I could write my code inside the template as if it was loaded outside a class.

Answer (score 0):

If by "istances of other classes" you mean other generical objects (you mention PDO and user which are goos examples of this) I would store these in the `$_SESSION` array (or in `$_GLOBAL` array, `$_SESSION` being the best option in most cases).

Then you can access them just by using `$_SESSION['PDO']->...` and the like

Answer (score 0):

One of the most popular method to handle php application rooting is to implement MVC design patern, or use an MVC Framework. Google 'MVC php' for details, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the functions [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) and [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php). Using these you can export variables from one scope to another.

A silly example could be: A function A transfer locally defined variable to a function B.

```
function A()
{
    $var1 = "1";
    $var2 = "2";
    // etc

    $data = get_defined_vars();
    B($data);

}

function B($data)
{
    extract($data);
    // somescript.php can use $var1, $var2, etc if B is call from A.
    require("somescript.php");
}

A();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use a [ServiceLocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) or an [InversionOfControll-Container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) to retrieve class instances without violation of [DI-Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). For your template file you can create view helper objects to have direct access to other objects.